# how to place two canvas with image on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have two canvas.One of them is a picture of a room and the other one is a picture of a chair.I have two question:
First:How to put these two canvas with images on each other?
Two: My first canvas which contains the image of the room is about 7 meters in width and the chair is about 80cm in width.By the way it's not the size of images.It's the size of their view.How should I put the second one according to the first one?

Thanks

Comment: do you think you can put one of the canvases inside a div with absolute position?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you keep referencing to a "canvas" as I can't see why you'd need canvas when you can just use images, but you can just use `position: relative;` on your parent element and then `position: absolute;` on your children elements, for example:

```
<div class="canvas">
    <img class="canvas__item" src="images/room.jpg" alt="The room">
    <img class="canvas__item  canvas__item--chair" src="images/chair.jpg" alt="The chair">
</div>
```

Or if using the `<canvas>` element (which I cannot tell without any code in your question):

```
<div class="canvas">
    <canvas class="canvas__item  canvas__item--room"></canvas>
    <canvas class="canvas__item  canvas__item--chair"></canvas>
</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.canvas {
    position: relative;
    width: 720px; /* Define the width of your main image, in your case the "room" */
    height: 460px; /* Define the height of your main image, in your case the "room" */
}

.canvas__item {
    position: absolute;
}    

.canvas__item--room {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.canvas__item--chair {
    top: 10px; /* Define the offset position of your chair image here */
    left: 80px; /* Define the offset position of your chair image here */
    width: 60px; /* Define the width of your chair image here */
    height: 180px; /* Define the height of your chair image here */
}
```

Comment: @james, This is not what he's asking... he wants to put two different canvases on the top of eachother!

Comment: Canvas is transparent, so this still applies. Without his code, how do we know? Poor English is hard to interpret, and to me, doesn't sound like he's referencing to two `<canvas>` elements at all hence the poorly constructed question.

Comment: @user3806613 kind of defeats what you're saying, as this still applies to canvas. See my above reply. It's unbelievable that a down vote has been given *even though* it answers his question to it's best authority with what he has given (which in all fairness is a poorly written question anyway) and I _didn't have to_ answer it.